# Formatar objeto resultado do JOIN

Tags: mysql, mysqli, sql-select, join

```
[PROFESSORES]
id | nome     |

1  | Gilson   |


[CURSOS]
id | nome      | professor_id

1  | Photoshop | 1
2  | AutoCad   | 1
```

Gostaria que no resultado do meu SELECT, o objeto venha no formato:
(Não necessariamente ou exatamente igual, quero apenas agrupar o resultado).

```
{
  id: 1,
  nome: 'gilson',
  CURSOS: [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'Photoshop',
      professor_id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: 'AutoCad',
      professor_id: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer esse agrupamento direto na Query, ou só manipulando via código mesmo ? (2 querys)